# TouchableOpacity only responds with a light touch

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, touchableopacity

I am currently trying to create an app using React native and I have multiple touchable opacity image buttons on different pages. However, whenever I click on any of the touchable opacity image buttons, it will ONLY work with a light tap/touch rather than a normal press on apps. I tried doing hit slop and it still doesn't avoid the issue of a light tap. Can someone please guide me on how to make this work as I have been stuck on this for days.

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() =>
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Track", {
          currentDate: this.state.currentDate,
        })
      }
    >
      <Image
        style={HomeStyles.ovalContainer}
        source={require("../../assets/oval.png")}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Thank you

Comment: The same is happening to me. Only a very light tap triggers onPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the touch opacity

```
setOpacityTo((value: number), (duration: number));
```

or you can also try Pressable component for e.g.

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction}>
  <Text>I'm pressable!</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `TouchableWihoutFeedback`

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => alert('Pressed!')}>
  <MyComponent />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
```